# Understanding Generic Class implementation

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to understand this code:

```
public interface IBuilding
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public class Model<TBuilding>
    where TBuilding : IBuilding
{
    public TBuilding Building { get; private set; }
}
```

What does `Model<TBuilding>` mean here? From my understanding, `ClassName<T>` stands for Generic Class. `<T>` can represent string, int etc. But `<TBuilding>` implements `IBuilding` interface here. Why does a generic type implement an interface? My suspicion is that `<T>` means `<Id>`. Am I correct?

I have no clue on how to understand this code. I read up on Generic Classes but could not find anything useful.

Comment: It doesn't implement an interface. It's saying that `TBuilding` must be of type `IBuilding`, so you can't do something like `new Model<string>()` because `string` isn't an `IBuilding`. It's called a [type parameter constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little misleading by naming

```cs
public interface IBuilding // interface contract
{
    string Id { get; }
    string ElevatorCount { get; }
}

// this is where you have confusion. T - is standard naming for generic type parameter
// if you start naming your generic type parameter TBuilding - 
// you will get confused that it might be some type
public class BuildingInspector<T>  where T : IBuilding // T : IBuilding - restricts types to IBuilding
{
    public BuildingInspector(T building) // generic type in constructor
    {
        Building = building;
    }

    public T Building { get; private set; }
    public int GetTotalElevatorCapacity(int kiloPerElevator)
    {
        return (this.Building.ElevatorCount * kiloPerElevator)  
    }
}

// U S A G E

public class SingleFamilyHome : IBuilding
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string ElevatorCount { get; private set; }
}
 . . . . .
private void TryUsingGenericType ()
{

    var famHome = new SingleFamilyHome(){ Id=1, ElevatorCount=0 };
    var famInspector = new BuildingInspector<SingleFamilyHome>(); // SUCCESS

    var capacity = famInspector.GetTotalElevatorCapacity(0);

    // this code will not compile because above you have --> where T : IBuilding
    var stringInspector = new BuildingInspector<string>(); // DESIGN TIME ERROR

}
```

Now that you see declaration AND usage, you can see how it is used.
Best example is `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`. You can have any list

```cs
List<string>
List<Building>
List<int>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I finally understand this. Your example helps a lot.

Comment: I have a follow up question:

So from your above example, bld has a property Building. How does the bld.Building relate to the SingleFamilyHome.Id? Does it mean that bld.Building has a Type SingleFamilyHome.Id?

Comment: @SY I added some missing components, so now it is better example. The idea of generic types is that same action can be dome on multiple types using strong typing. In the old example `bld.Building` was related to `SingleFamilyHome.Id` like this. Former was holding ANY `IBuilding` as reference and `IBuilding` exposed API - `Id`. This is all the relation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to expand on your answer. Appreciate it. I understand now. :)

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly. `T` is just a placeholder for a type. If you have `FireHouse`, `PoliceStation`, `Hospital`, etc. implementing `IBuilding` you can provide one of those to `Model` and the `Building` property would only hold an instance of that type.

Answer (score 1):

'Where' syntax is constraining your T type to be a type that implements IBuilding. Without the where condition, it would accept any types. Here you can find a more detailed explanation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: "to be a type that implements IBuilding" in this case yes, but it could also be a inheritance relationship. So in general it constraints a type and not specifically an implementation of an interface

Comment: Yes, you're right, maybe I wrote it a bit in a hurry.